# Jquery version change issue with Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle-apex

I have a piece of code as highlighted below that was working on Jquery 1.4.1, but we recently migrated to Jquery version 3.0.0 and it started failing. So after much googling, I made a change to the code as shown below and it started working again.

```
$("fieldset#P24_PUB_IND").click(function(){ .... //in Jquery 1.4.1

 // Changed the above line to 

$("#P24_PUB_IND input:radio").click(function(){ .... // in Jquery 3.0.0
```

My question is why are all other similar code patterns still working after the migration, codes like the ones highlighted below still work in Jquery 3.0.0

```
$("input#P24_REQUEST_TYPE").val();  // This works both in Jquery 1.4.1 and Jquery 3.0.0
$("select#P24_PUB_TYPE").val();  // This works both in Jquery 1.4.1 and Jquery 3.0.0
```

Can anyone please explain, thanks in advance.

Comment: include html into question

Comment: I'm not sure this involves any version differences; the two queries select different things. The first query selects a `<fieldset>` with the specified ID and the second one selects radio inputs inside an element with that ID. It might help to include your HTML, any other [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and a description of what specifically goes wrong when switching to jQuery 3.

Answer (score 1):

Now I got it, Prior to the migration the HTML tag looked like this below

`<fieldset tabindex="-1" id="P24_PUB_IND" class="radio_group apex-item-radio"> 
.......... 
</fieldset>`

After the Migration it looks like

`<div tabindex="-1" id="P24_PUB_IND" class="radio_group apex-item-group" role="group" aria-labelledby="P24_PUB_IND_LABEL"> 
...... 
</div>`

Now I need to verify why the DOM changed after migration. But for the things that were already working in both the versions they had their tags intact and that's the reason they did not have any issues.

Comment: its only the check boxes that have their tags changed. Need to investigate more. Thanks all for taking your time in trying to help me. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Ashlesh, check out my series on getting started with APEX and JavaScript here (I started this at the part where I describe the issue that you ran into): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02thxqv-m_c&list=PLUo-NIMouZ_sgdQpMbXXwhHKpwRggCY34&index=2&t=2m36s

Comment: @Dan McGhan, Thanks for the video. So you recon the radio button in "5.1" version of Oracle APEX has "Fieldset" tag and this tag gets changed to "div" when we migrate right ? Is there a document which states this ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics, but any time you upgrade APEX the HTML output can change. Typically it doesn't change much, but even a small change could break your code. So if you add JavaScript to an APEX app, you always have to retest it after an upgrade.

Comment: As for doc, these changes are not documented. If you use the declarative parts of Dynamic Actions, the team will account for any changes for you automatically. However, when you add custom JavaScript, you have to manually test and update it.

Comment: Thanks to all, I modified the JS file to accommodate the new HTML changes and now it is working fine. I have to test the whole application now :(

Comment: Not the "whole" application. Just the parts with custom JavaScript. :)